# How to use the filename of an excel file to change a column of cells?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write an excel macro/VBA code to adjust a column's contents based off the title of the file. Currently,  I have a macro setup to download a csv file based off a URL I type in. The macro automatically formats and names the file. I want to use the first 5 characters of the file's name/title to automatically format additional cells.

For example, the filename is 48GHY_fjfdkjfe33.RHRH-msadklfjeiojo. I have a column in my file called name+type. I want to combine the "name" row with the title and have it populate the fields. The two images below provide a before and after.

[image: Before Database]

[image: After Database]

Currently, I have to type in the first 5 characters into a seperate field and then use the:
="48GHY"&a2 function.

Is there a way to do this in excel/VBA?

---

The original question was answered, but now I am seeking additional help when trying to put it in a macro. Because it is still the same question, I do not think it warrants another post.

Here is the current macro/VBA I am using. When ever I run this, it just displays #VALUE! in the cell. The only thing different between the two sets of code is that the A and B columns are now J and K.

```
' Insert Column after name and then rename it name+type

Rows(1).Find("name").Offset(0, 1).EntireColumn.Insert
Rows(1).Find("name").Offset(0, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "name+type"
```

' Freeze the Top Row

```
Rows("1:1").Select
With ActiveWindow
    .SplitColumn = 0
    .SplitRow = 1
End With
ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
```

'Save the file

```
ActiveWorkbook.Save
```

'Add the contents to the name+type column

```
Range("K2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=LEFT(MID(CELL(""filename"",RC[-1]),SEARCH(""["",CELL(""filename"",RC[-1]))+1,SEARCH(""]"",CELL(""filename"",RC[-1]))-SEARCH(""["",CELL(""filename"",RC[-1]))-1),5)&RC[-1]"
Range("K2").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("K2:K8294").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

' Autofit all Columns

```
Columns("A:AK").Select
Selection.Columns.AutoFit
```

End Sub

*One additional comment. I modified the code you provided in the macro, but in each cell after I run it the following code is in column k:

```
=LEFT(MID(CELL("filename",J2),SEARCH("[",CELL("filename",J2))+1,SEARCH("]",CELL("filename",J2))-SEARCH("[",CELL("filename",J2))-1),5)&J2
```

*Last note. The file name is being saved as 48GHY_fjfdkjfe33.RHRH-msadklfjeiojo#csv.txt (Could that have anything to do with it?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put this in B2

`=LEFT(MID(CELL("filename",A2),SEARCH("[",CELL("filename",A2))+1, SEARCH("]",CELL("filename",A2))-SEARCH("[",CELL("filename",A2))-1),5)&A2`

**EDIT**

**Explanation**

This formula `=CELL("filename",A2)` gives you the file name. For example

`C:\Users\Siddharth Rout\Desktop\[Book1.xlsx]Sheet1`

and this formula

`=MID(CELL("filename",A2),SEARCH("[",CELL("filename",A2))+1, SEARCH("]",CELL("filename",A2))-SEARCH("[",CELL("filename",A2))-1)`

takes out just the file name from above to give you `Book1.xlsx`

The `Left()` returns the first character or characters in a text string, based on the number of characters you specify.

HTH

Comment: +1 There we go, posting almost the same thing at the same time.

Comment: Would it matter if the filename is not saved locally, or a READ-ONLY?

Comment: @Jonny: You don't have to type in the file name :) Just copy and paste the formula as it is :)

Comment: Weird. I was running into #value errors when the file wasn't saved locally. Once I saved it the code worked great.

Comment: Yes, for this formula to work, the file has to be saved first else how will you get the file name ;)?

Comment: Nice - you might want to add a reference in the second argument of the CELL function as Scott suggests so the workbook name stays fixed when you recalculate with another workbook active.

Comment: This is not working after I include it in a macro to automatically save the file. Does it have to be saved as a certain file extension? Currently mine is saved as a file#csv.xlsm

Comment: @Rout: Should I start under a new post?

Comment: @Jonny: It is entirely up to you :)

Comment: I figured it out. When using this line in a macro, make sure that all the quotes are double quotes. That seemed to have fixed my problem

Comment: @Rout: It is still not working in the macro. I have edited my original post with the code. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you don't even need VBA. Something like this worked for me.

```
=MID(CELL("filename",A2),FIND("[",CELL("filename",A2))+1,5) & A2
```

Lookup Cell formula to understand how filename works.

Comment: + 1 Yup. Same timing again :)

Comment: Yes, but went the extra mile on this one, though.

Comment: The code worked great once I saved the file locally, but was returning a #value error when a READ-ONLY file