# How to use column headers to select different ranges of cells to populate data from a filename

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

This is a separate question stemming from this post: [How to use the filename of an excel file to change a column of cells?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11192167/how-to-use-the-filename-of-an-excel-file-to-change-a-column-of-cells)

I noticed that in the last post's code it was referencing specific cells (J2,K2). However when using the code, I came into an error when the columns changed. So now I am seeking a way to modify the below code to use the names of the header columns to populate the 2nd column instead of referencing specific cells. I think the only line that really needs adjusting is the myRng line, but I will provide all the code I am trying for reference.

In case you don't read the other post, I will describe the issue. I am trying to fill in the 2nd column (name+type) based on the "name" column and the filename. When I was referencing the K or J row in the code, everything was working fine, but when I load a different file and the columns positions  have changed, everything gets messed up.

I need to populate the 2nd column (name+type) to be the exactly the same number or rows as the 1st column (name) which is why I am using the Range ("K2:K" & lastCell) formula.

Is there a way to do this?

Current Attempted VBA code:

```
' Insert Column after name and then rename it name+type

Rows(1).Find("name").Offset(0, 1).EntireColumn.Insert
Rows(1).Find("name").Offset(0, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "name+type"

Dim myRng As Range
Dim lastCell As Long
Dim myOtherRange As Range
Dim column2Range As Range

myOtherRange = Rows(1).Find("name")
column2Range = Rows(1).Find("name+type")
lastCell = Range(myOtherRange).End(xlDown).Row
Set myRng = Range("K2:K" & lastCell)

myOtherRange.FormulaR2C1 = "=LEFT(MID(CELL(""filename""),SEARCH(""["",CELL(""filename""))+1, SEARCH(""]"",CELL(""filename""))-SEARCH(""["",CELL(""filename""))-1),5)&RC[-1]"
myOtherRange.FormulaR2C1.Select
Selection.Copy
myRng.Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

First Draft VBA code:

```
' Insert Column after name and then rename it name+type

Rows(1).Find("name").Offset(0, 1).EntireColumn.Insert
Rows(1).Find("name").Offset(0, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "name+type"


'Add the contents to the name+type column

Range("K2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=LEFT(MID(CELL(""filename"",RC[-1]),SEARCH(""["",CELL(""filename"",RC[-1]))+1,SEARCH(""]"",CELL(""filename"",RC[-1]))-SEARCH(""["",CELL(""filename"",RC[-1]))-1),5)&RC[-1]"
Range("K2").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("K2:K8294").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Comment: See if this fixes it -> `Set myRng = Range(Cells(2,column2Range.Column),Cells(lastCell,column2Range.Column)` This is certainly a cleaner way to do this, but that should get your range set properly, no matter which column your name+type header is in pretty easily in your current code

Comment: also bear in mind that `lastCell = Range(myOtherRange).End(xlDown).Row` will give you results you don't like if that column has any blanks cells before the data set ends. Better to say this to get the true last cell `lastCell = Cells(Rows.Count, Range(myOtherRange).Column).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: I actually delete any blank cells earlier in the macro, but thanks for the thought! I just tried to implement that code, but am getting a 91 run-time error: Object variable or With block variable not set. I am getting it on this time `myOtherRange = Rows(1).Find("name")`. Is this because the variable is not a range?

Comment: look in Row 1, is the word "name" there? Also, look at the `.Find` method, to see how to use its arguments, especially `LookAt` and `LookIn`

Comment: @Scott when I change the other range variables to "Set rn" then I get a `Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed` error

Comment: Its just `Set myOtherRange = Rows(1).Find("name")`. Also, see my last comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After modifying the code provided by Siddharth, this is the final code that worked for me. The save feature needed to also remove a format and the Formula to search and add the filename to the cells did not work without this edit. I also had to change the sheet to the activeSheet, because it was constantly changing. Here is the code:

```
Sub Naming()

Dim LR As Long, i As Long, lngCol As Long

lngCol = Rows(1).Find("NAME", lookat:=xlWhole).Column 'assumes there will always be a column with "NAME" in row 1

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

LR = Cells(Rows.Count, lngCol).End(xlUp).Row

For i = LR To 1 Step -1

    If Len(Cells(i, lngCol).Value) < 4 Then Rows(i).Delete

Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

' Insert Column after NAME and then rename it NAME+TYPE

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long, aCol As Long
Dim aCell As Range

Set ws = ActiveSheet 'Need to change to the Active sheet

With ws
    Set aCell = .Rows(1).Find("NAME")

    ' Check if the column with "NAME" is found, it is assumed earlier
    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
        aCol = aCell.Column
        .Columns(aCol + 1).EntireColumn.Insert
        .Cells(1, aCol + 1).Value = "NAME+TYPE"
        .Activate

    ' Freeze the Top Row

    Rows("1:1").Select
    With ActiveWindow
        .SplitColumn = 0
        .SplitRow = 1
    End With
    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True

        ' Get lastrow of Col which has "NAME"
        lRow = .Range(Split(.Cells(, aCol).Address, "$")(1) & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        'Save the file and format the filetype
        Dim wkb As Workbook
        Set wkb = ActiveWorkbook 'change to your workbook reference
        wkb.SaveAs Replace(wkb.Name, "#csv.gz", ""), 52 'change "csv.gz" to ".xlsm" if need be

        ' Add the formula to all the cells in 1 go.
        .Range(Split(.Cells(, aCol + 1).Address, "$")(1) & "2:" & _
        Split(.Cells(, aCol + 1).Address, "$")(1) & lRow).Formula = _
        "=LEFT(MID(CELL(""filename""),SEARCH(""["",CELL(""filename""))+1, SEARCH(""]"",CELL(""filename""))-SEARCH(""["",CELL(""filename""))-1),5)&RC[-1]"

        .Columns("A:AK").Columns.AutoFit
    Else
        MsgBox "NAME Column Not Found"
    End If
 End With

' Change the Range of the cursor

Range("A1").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

> @Scott or Siddharth Rout probably =) – Jonny 11 hours ago

I would never recommend this :) SO is full of experts who can assist you. Why do you want to limit the help that you can get? ;)

Is this what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long, aCol As Long
    Dim aCell As Range

    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1") '<~~ Change this to the relevant sheet name

    With ws
        Set aCell = .Rows(1).Find("Name")

        '~~> Check if the column with "name" is found
        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
            aCol = aCell.Column
            .Columns(aCol + 1).EntireColumn.Insert
            .Cells(1, aCol + 1).Value = "Name+Type"
            .Activate

            .Rows(1).Select

            With ActiveWindow
                .SplitColumn = 0
                .SplitRow = 1
                .FreezePanes = True
            End With

            '~~> Get lastrow of Col which has "name"
            lRow = .Range(Split(.Cells(, aCol).Address, "$")(1) & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

            ThisWorkbook.Save

            '~~> Add the formula to all the cells in 1 go.
            .Range(Split(.Cells(, aCol + 1).Address, "$")(1) & "2:" & _
            Split(.Cells(, aCol + 1).Address, "$")(1) & lRow).Formula = _
            "=LEFT(MID(CELL(""filename"",RC[-1]),SEARCH(""["",CELL(""filename"",RC[-1]))+1," & _
            "SEARCH(""]"",CELL(""filename"",RC[-1]))-SEARCH(""["",CELL(""filename"",RC[-1]))-1),5)&RC[-1]"

            .Columns("A:AK").Columns.AutoFit
        Else
            MsgBox "Name Column Not Found"
        End If
     End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I agree. I would never want to limit SO or the users; it was simply a friendly gesture because you both have helped me so much.

Comment: What if the sheet name is not consistent, but is generated every time a different URL is open?

Comment: would i change it to `Set ws = Workbook.ActiveSheet`?

Comment: Yes you can set it to the `Activesheet` like you have done in your answer :)